# Understanding the concept of hole in semiconductor physics

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, quasiparticles

I've studied the Kronig–Penney model and learned about the effective mass theory and I know that at the top of the valence band the effective mass of electrons are negative, this is just an introduction about the information I know to ask the question properly.

My question is: In case of semiconductor an empty state is called hole and it has an positive charge and positive effective mass also, but what really is a hole and how did we introduce this concept and how to understand it? Because a lot of textbooks gives different interpretations to it and I can't understand it correctly.

Comment: With all due respect, please take more time write/ type the question. There were a lot of typos etc.. This makes the question harder to read for everyone. Moreover, a good formatted question will likely attract more people, raising the chances of obtaining a good answer, I'd say.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/755026/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You shouldn't see different interpretations as a problem. They are stories about the phenomena. As long as they are experimentally consistent with the phenomena, they are all good stories, with different insights to be be had.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the concept of hole in semiconductor physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/755026/)

Comment: There are different levels of introducing a hole: from describing a jumping vacancy, to effective mass approximation, to obtaining it as a quasiparticle pole in green's function. I post this as a comment, since I have already given an answer in the question linked by @Qmechanic. But I would be glad to expand it, if more precision is required.